# Google Maps for Android v2 - Importing separate java file

Tags: java, android, eclipse, maps, adt

For my school project we have to work with the Google Maps API v2 for Android (with Eclipse ADT).

We are creating an app that keeps track of your location during Running or Cycling exercises. This means that the Fragment of the Map only has to be 50% off the screen. Because we would like to keep our code looking nice and clean, I wanted to create a separate .java file which stores the code for the Google Maps Fragment.

The .java class for our "WORKOUT PAGE" called Workout.java has code for a stopwatch and some other info, and is already an FragmentActivity.

How would I start off creating the GoogleMaps.java file (with or without an activity?) and how would I import this into Workout.java?

Thanks!

Edit: Could I use something like this in Workout.java?

```
GoogleMaps map = new GoogleMaps();
```

How would I be able to import this into my Fragment in Workout.java later on?

Comment: You can't create `GoogleMaps` object but, you can get it either from `SupportMapFragment` or `MapFragment`.

Comment: Yes, but this would require me to put all the additional code (like leaving a trail for the runners route etc, calculating distance runner etc.) inside my Workout.java right? And I actually wanted everything related to GoogleMaps in a separate class while still running the fragment inside Workout.java . Would that be possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can extend SupportMapFragment and put your map related logic there (ex: marker management)

```
public class CustomMapFragment extends SupportMapFragment {

private GoogleMap googleMap;
private List<Marker> markers = new ArrayList<Marker>();

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    googleMap = getMap();
    ViewUtils.initializeMargin(getActivity(), view);
    return view;
}

private void addMarkerToMap(LatLng latLng) {
    Marker marker = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng)
             .title("title")
             .snippet("snippet"));
    markers.add(marker);

}

/**
 * Adds a list of markers to the map.
 */
public void addMarkersToMap(List<LatLng> latLngs) {
    for (LatLng latLng : latLngs) {
        addMarkerToMap(latLng);
    }
}

/**
 * Clears all markers from the map.
 */
public void clearMarkers() {
    googleMap.clear();
    markers.clear();        
}
```

}

You can then add that custom MapFragment in your layout (along with other fragments)

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/workout"
    android:name="com.foobar.WorkoutFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.foobar.CustomMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

That way you seperate the pure map related code from the rest of your codebase.